# upgrading scipy in mac

Tags: scipy, pip

I want to upgrade scipy. and I used pip install scipy --upgrade to do this, but here is error, how should I fix this?

```
    Installing collected packages: scipy
  Found existing installation: scipy 0.13.0b1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (scipy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling scipy-0.13.0b1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/7x/1ly_pjjd3g50632kc7mc68n00000gn/T/pip-a37H18-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy-0.13.0b1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Comment: I also tried using sudo, it's the same

Answer (score 5):

Python version 2.7.10

Mac version 10.12.04

I tried to install face_recognition, then display the same problem.

```
sudo pip install face_recognition
```

try use:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade scipy --ignore-installed six
```